# Hide certain links of a navbar if the screen width is less than a certain width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My navbar is supposed to be responsive. How can I hide the other links apart from a logo link called `logo` when the screen size is less than 680px? Thanks.

Comment: Consider to provide your sample code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `media` query like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
    .navbar a:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Assuming that your **logo link** is an anchor (`a`)